# Belgium, road closure A11?

Tags: driving, belgium

I'm going to drive from Antwerp out coastwards later today, google maps says A11 is closed

[image]

No more info in google (apart from maps). Anyone from Belgium, could you clarify what's going on?

Comment: This question is going to go out of date really quickly.

Comment: This question is far too specific to be of long-term value. If it were broadened to "how do I find out road closure issues in Belgium?", it might be of more future value.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier: or "in Europe" in general, because it's not the first time I notice Maps to be unreliable in this respect. I'm personally not particularly interested, but feel free to edit.

Comment: An answer for Belgium is more likely to be meaningful than one for all of Europe, as each country may have their own road closures reporting system, for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I recall I got the same notice on my phone last night, after having taken that exact road to get home. It seems to either be a bug or they've interpreted a traffic notice incorrectly: there **are** roadworks on that particular freeway with single-lane traffic from Vrasene (on the left on your map) going east to just past where it joins the R2 with part of the exit closed (E34 > R2 closed, take next exit; R2 > E34 West closed; R2 > E34 open).

However, since you're driving west, not east, you shouldn't even encounter any delays. That road is most definitely open.

Additional source to confirm: [Verkeerscentrum.be](http://www.verkeerscentrum.be/verkeersinfo/kaart?erp=3dQ6yOtK%2Bdsde3s7d%2FC9KG6rBu3tHgV1p%2FZQ%2FGFySiWBMxwIDNhxPTIJL%2F9IHQZuImgE85l5TMS11hvCLVTCYQ%3D%3D)

Comment: Thanks, everything went fine (except that you usually don't expect to see that many traffic lights on a freeway :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not from Belgium, but I suspect it *might* be a bug.  The A11 in the UK was closed today following a collision (see [twitter tweets about it](https://twitter.com/search?f=realtime&q=a11%20closed&src=typd) and perhaps Google's placed it on the wrong A11.

Comment: @pnuts Or, on the opposite, an alarmingly wrong automation.